# ICMP Header Malconstructed?

Tags: python, sockets, networking, icmp

I'm creating a pinger in python and using this is my ICMP packet:

```
ICMP_PACKET = '\x08\x00\xF7\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

Is there any issues with this packet? I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. The entire code is this:

```
ICMP_HEADER = '\x08\x00\xF7\x00\x00\x00\x00'
ipadd = socket.gethostbyname('www.google.com')
socket.setdefaulttimeout(1)
try:
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, 1)
    sock.sendto(header, (ipadd, 0))
    reply = sock.recv(1024)
    print(reply)
except:
    pass
```

Comment: And what happens when you run your program? You might want to actually catch any exceptions and print them out, or it will be impossible to know what happened when something goes wrong. Also, you have remembered that the packet should be in network byte order?

Comment: No on network byte order... How would I do that?